# <a> tag href to website page in htm template

Tags: asp.net

I have some htm templates that I use to send email messages within my website. One of these has a hardcoded web address in the development environment. (The ip address is where we temporarily host it for testing) Now that it will be hosted, how do I set this href so it always resolves to the path to that page. I could just retrieve the path every time the link is clicked and rewrite the htm file but that seems inefficient, there must be a way to resolve within the htm template itself.

```
<p>
        <b>Your temporary Password is:&#32;</b><i><%Password%></i><br/>
        Follow this link to change your password<br/>
        <!--the href below will have to be changed once its hosted-->
        <a href="**http://25.39.286.15/Account/ChangePassword.aspx**"> Change your password here </a>
    </p>
```

I've tried it this way but it generates a coding error in VS2012 at the left angle bracket of the Page.ResolveUrl

```
<a href='<%#Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("Account/ChangePassword.aspx"))%>'> Change your password here </a>
```

Comment: is there a reason to hardcode the entire path?  why not use relative path: /Account/ChangePassword.aspx

Comment: I was using that in the beginning and of course that works fine in the development environment but it wasn't when we put the site up on the temporary host server, thus the problem. This is an htm template, not aspx markup.

Comment: On the temporary host server, does your application run in a virtual directory or the root in IIS?

Comment: Runs in IIS, not sure if in the root, would have to ask the server manager

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work, regardless of location?

```
<a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx") %>">Change Password</a>
```